# Trouble with includeDocuments in DocuSign API EventNotification when using restv2.1

Tags: docusignapi

I have successfully gotten event notifications (webhooks) working with my DocuSign demo account, but when I change the `eventData` version to `restv2.1` by including this in my EventNotification:

```
eventData: {
  version: 'restv2.1'
}
```

DocuSign seems to start ignoring the value of my `includeDocuments` argument on the events. What I'm really trying to do is to get notified when each recipient signs (but without the documents), and then also get notified when the envelope is completed (with the documents). However, thanks to the `includeDocuments` flag having no effect, it seems I only have two options:

1. Don't get any documents back
2. Include `includeData: ['documents']` in my `eventData` and get documents back on EVERYTHING. Not just my actual documents, but a certificate document as well.

Has anyone had any luck getting the documents only when you request them with `restv2.1`?

Answer (score 2):

When you create an Envelope, in the API defined a section for the request, which allows you to define the desired format of the data: [connecteventdata](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#parameters_connecteventdata)

Documentation of this object also links an [article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/connect-webhooks-json-notifications), which explains it in more details.

So, you have more options to specify the `includeData` among with the **"documents"** example:

> The **eventNotification** object now includes a new attribute, **eventData**. The attribute is set to an object with three attributes: {*version*, *format*, and *includeData*}

> **includeData** is an array of strings with valid items: *"custom_fields", "extensions", "folders", "recipients", "powerform", "tabs", "payment_tabs", "documents", "attachments"* - see description by the first link, [1](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#parameters_connecteventdata)